# Determine the rank of $AB$, given matrices $A$ which is $m \times n$ and $B$ which is $n \times $p$ - proof assistence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with rank $m$ and $B$ be an $n \times p$ matrix with rank $n$. Determine the rank of $AB$. Justify your answer.

So to begin after doing some specialized examples I worked out that the rank of the matrix $AB$ will be $m$. Now I'm having difficulties proving it.

First off in the textbook I'm using *(Linear Algebra, Friedberg, Insel, et al)*, the definition of the rank is the following:

> If $A \in M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, we define the rank of $A$, denoted $rank(A)$, to be the rank of the linear transformation $L_{A}:\mathbb{F}^{n} \to \mathbb{F}^{m}$, where $L_{A}$ is the left multiplication transformation, $L_{A}(x) = Ax$ for $x \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$. And as a result $L_{B}: \mathbb{F}^{p} \to \mathbb{F}^{n}$ is the left multiplication transformation, $L_{B}(x) = Bx$ for $x \in \mathbb{F}^{p}$

Since I deduced that the rank of $AB = m$, that means I have to show that $rank(AB) = rank (A)$. THis means:

$$rank(L_{AB}) = rank(L_{A}) \\ \Rightarrow\ dim(R(L_{AB})) = dim(R(L_{A})),\\ \text{where $R$ is the range of a linear transformation}$$

So it means I have to show that:

$$dim(R(L_{A}L_{B})) = m$$

So form here to me I deduced that somehow I have to show that $R(L_{A}L_{B}) = R(L_{A})$

And this is where I'm stuck. There was a proof I saw that used the idea of $L_{B}(\mathbb{F^{p}}) = \mathbb{F^{n}}$ but that seemed very much off because for that to be the case, it must be that $L_{B}$ is invertible, which it may not necessarily be. Perhaps my approach is wrong, but I feel I'm close to what I need to accomplish but can't seem to see what last steps I need to take. Some assistance would be nice.

Comment: you should be able to infer that $B$ is surjective (so it has a right inverse) and $A$  is also surjective (so it too has a right inverse)

Comment: I don't remember establishing any results that discuss if a matrix is surjective that it has an inverse. The only result I have with regards to inverses is if the matrices are squared matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple proof:

$B$ is surjective, so Im $AB =$ Im $A$, so rank$(AB) =$ rank$(A) = m$.

To see $B$ is surjective, just note that $B$ maps to a $n$-dimensional space and has rank $n$.

Comment: Wouldn't $B$ map to a $p$-dimensional space ? since $L_{B}:\mathbb{F}^{m} \to \mathbb{F}^{p}$

Comment: The $B$ in the problem is $n$ x $p$... (different than the $B$ in the definition that you quote.)

Comment: Hmmm. I worked it out and the mapping relationship is clear. The number of rows will imply the dimension of the codomain. So establishing this idea, would the following be a way to finish the proof: $L_{A}L_{B}(x) = L_{A}(L_{B}(x)) = L_{A}(R(L_{B}))$ and since we know $B$ is surjective this means $R(L_{B}) = \mathbb{F}^{n}$. Therefore $L_{A}(\mathbb{F}^{n})$ and the rank of this is $m$.

Comment: Basically, informally one might write $L_AL_B(\mathbb{F}^p) = L_A(\mathbb{F}^n) = R(L_A)$ and then take dimensions.

Comment: Yes, eventually I was going to take dimensions and such, but didn't want to clutter up my comment. Thanks for the help